# Springboot exception handling when there is no controllers

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I have a spring-boot application without any controller classes.
How can I write exception handlers for this application. Exception handler classes annotated with @ControllerAdvice doesn't work.

Comment: ExceptionHandler and ControllerAdvice are used to handle controller level exceptions. For method level exception handling, you have to use classic try/catch blocks. Refer https://www.ekiras.com/2016/02/how-to-do-exception-handling-in-springboot-rest-application.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing [web applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-web-applications), [`ErrroController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) is available.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}")
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    public MyErrorController(final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final WebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request);
        final Throwable th = errorAttributes.getError(webRequest);

        // ...
        // see also: BasicErrorController implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have any controller class in my application